# Excel VBA to select PivotField and associated data values with that PivotField row

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to select all the data cells associated with one particular PivotField from the Row items, how do i do that?

My data looks something like this:

```
          Sum of x  Sum of y  Sum of z
Class1       2.5        1         2
   *Name1    *1        *0        *0
   *Name2    *1        *1        *1
   *Name3    *.5       *0        *1
Class2       3.8       2.6        2
   *NameA    *1        *1        *0
   *NameB   *0.8       *0        *1
   *NameC    *1       *0.6       *0 
   *NameD    *1        *1        *1
```

Now, I only wanna select the data with * in front and perform conditional formatting - if the cell value is less than 1, highlight the cell. If it's greater than 1, highlight it with different color. I am having trouble selecting the data range I want as explained above.

Here is attempted code: (error: object doesn't support this property or method)

```
Sub formatPivotTable()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("test")

Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems.DataRange.Select (error: object doesnt support this property or method)

With pf.DataRange
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End With
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=1"
    With .FormatConditions(2)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd need to `Select` anything... untested, but based on the example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotitem.datarange) what if you change that line to `Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Name")`?

Comment: @BigBen that selected my rows only and not the data fields.It selected all row items from Class1 to NameD. i only want to select name row and associated data field.

Comment: I've always found Jon Peltier's [explanation](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) of how to select pivot table ranges helpful. If I have time later I might be able to take a second look at your issue.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen that would help a lot. I did take a look at Jon Peltier's explanation but i could not find what i am looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

The code below:

1. Loops through each `pivotItem` in the "Name" `pivotField` and builds up a `namesRange` using `Union`. The `namesRange` corresponds to `$B$5:$B$7,$B$9:$B$12` in the screenshot.
2. Then uses `Intersect`, `namesRange.EntireRow` and the `DataBodyRange` of the entire pivot table to get a `condFormRange`. The `condFormRange` corresponds to `$B$5:$D$7,$B$9:$D$12` in the screenshot.

From there the conditional formatting is as you already have it.

```
Sub FormatPivotTable()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("test")

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Name")

    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim namesRange As Range

    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If namesRange Is Nothing Then
            Set namesRange = pi.DataRange
        Else
            Set namesRange = Union(namesRange, pi.DataRange)
        End If
    Next pi

    Debug.Print namesRange.Address ' returns $B$5:$B$7,$B$9:$B$12

    If Not namesRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim condFormRange As Range
        Set condFormRange = Intersect(namesRange.EntireRow, pt.DataBodyRange)
        Debug.Print condFormRange.Address ' returns $B$5:$D$7,$B$9:$D$12

        With condFormRange
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1"

            With .FormatConditions(1)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=1"

            With .FormatConditions(2)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]